# Remove a linked library from Xcode

Tags: xcode

I'm new using Xcode and I've made a mistake.

I added a folder with `.h` and `.m` files through Linked Frameworks and libraries from general tab.

Now I want to remove it but the folder is not in the list.

Comment: Did you search it in your project folder in Finder?

Comment: Yes, and I removed it, but project builds fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to add the files again normally, maybe then they show up in the side-bar. Then you can delete them properly.

Also you can try to look at the error message. Click on the red warning-sign in the top bar of Xcode. Then, tap on the error which might bring you to the missing file where you can delete it.

Hope it helps :)